# Search for a value in a file and remove subsequent lines

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm developing a shell script but I am stuck with the below part.

I have the file `sample.txt`:

```
S.No    Sub1    Sub2
1       100     200
2       100     200
3       100     200
4       100     200
5       100     200
6       100     200
7       100     200
```

I want to search the `S.No` column in `sample.txt`. For example if I'm searching the value `5` I need the rows up to 5 only `I` don't want the rows after the value of in `S.NO` is larger than 5.

the output must look like, `output.txt`

```
S.No    Sub1    Sub2
1       100     200
2       100     200
3       100     200
4       100     200
5       100     200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the first line and any other line where the first field is less than or equal to 5:

```
$ awk 'NR==1||$1<=5' file
S.No    Sub1    Sub2
1       100     200
2       100     200
3       100     200
4       100     200
5       100     200
```

Comment: i have modified the code like `awk -F ':' 'NR==1||$2<=$ZerodollarHour' file` but it's not working

Comment: I declared `ZerodollarHour=date '+%H'`

Comment: i got it `awk -F ':' 'NR==1||$2<='$ZerodollarHour'' file` did. Thank you so much!

Comment: The correct way would be to use the `-v` option  `awk -F: -v z="$ZerodollarHour" 'NR==1||$2<=z' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[$1]<=5' file
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when then value of `S.No` is 11 or 123 ect... This is not a problem for regexp!

Comment: @sudo_O True, changed the answer to use `perl`. It's not that OP cannot get the desired output with a `regex` albeit might get too complex to handle every edge scenario.

Answer (score 1):

And the sed solution

```
n=5
sed "/^$n[[:space:]]/q" filename
```

The sed `q` command exits after printing the current line

Answer (score 0):

The suggested awk relies on that column 1 is numeric sorted. A generic awk that fulfills the question title would be:

```
gawk -v p=5 '$1==p {print; exit} {print}'
```

However, in this situation, sed is better IMO. Use -i to modify the input file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '6q' sample.txt > output.txt
```